# TensorFlow unable to set large precision of tensors for 12 decimals with float 64

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision, floating-accuracy

Hello i am using TensorFlow i have i try to load float 64 tensor value but when i load to i loose decimals any help?

```
 tenosr = tf.constant([57.695030261422, 11.911734826863], dtype=tf.float64)
```

[image]

Comment: Please read this article before posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Thank you.

Comment: it doesnt loss decimals, it just shows fewer desimals. Check, `tenosr * 1e5 - tf.math.floor(tenosr * 1e5) gives  [0.0261422, 0.4826863]`

Comment: @V.M any way to force it to show the whole value?